# How to I send information from a Desktop app to android app?

Tags: android, mysql, server, desktop, windows

I am looking to make an app which suggest to people the estimated waiting time depending on number of doctors and number of patients in a clinic. What i understand is I need to do a MySQL database app in the desktop which sends the information to a APACHE server and then the server will send it to the end-user android app?

Comment: use this https://pusher.com.. this is super great push data in realtime in any platform

Answer (score 0):

U can use push notification feature for that
Please check below links

https://www.betaout.com/web-push
[enter link description here](https://www.betaout.com/web-push)

https://pushed.co/

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can do that. For beginners, one way is to use the **ksoap2 library**, which facilitates communication with server and device.

Here is a tutorial that shows you step by step, how to create a **MySQL Database + a WebService and the implementation with Android**:

Part 1:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J87qN3B-dI

Part 2:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utLxvFHkTPg

It is in Portuguese, but the video is well didactic and easy to follow.